# A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type JSON MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I follow the instructions of this video [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5CIMlLNOe4)

In my controller:

```
public ActionResult loaddatacate()
        {
            BBDbModel context = new BBDbModel();
            context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            var data = context.Drinks_Category.ToList();
            return Json(new { data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

In my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function (e) {
            $("#example1").DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Admin/AdminHome/loaddatacate",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "Id_category", "autowidth": true },
                    { "data": "Name_category", "autowidth": true },
                    { "data": "Parent", "autowidth": true }
                ]
            });
            var Parent =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Parent));
            $(".parent").autocomplete({
                source: Parent
            });
        });
```

Table "Drinks_category" in database have 3 columns: Id_category,Name_category,Parent

Error is:

A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'WebApplication3.Models.Framework.Drinks_Category'.

Drinks_Category class:

```
public partial class Drinks_Category
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Drinks_Category()
        {
            Drinks = new HashSet<Drink>();
            Drinks_Category1 = new HashSet<Drinks_Category>();
        }

        [Key]
        [StringLength(10)]
        public string Id_category { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Name_category { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(10)]
        public string Parent { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Drink> Drinks { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Drinks_Category> Drinks_Category1 { get; set; }

        public virtual Drinks_Category Drinks_Category2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: how is the db laid out, and what are the restrictions?

Comment: I do not understand your question, BBDbModel is a DbContext

Comment: Var data is an exact list, I thought it was an error due to JSON

Comment: The circular reference is coming from a table. We don't know how it looks like neither the data mappings

Comment: Please take a look at this photo [link](http://www.upsieutoc.com/image/YAnfgy)

Comment: Maybe post your Drinks_Category class too please.

Comment: Just update the post with code and images. Outside links are discouraged

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on `data` before your `return` call to see if your results are good i.e. non proxy classes with the number of results you expect to have and they are only the `Drinks_Category` objects and no other eager loaded entities?

Comment: An easier alternative to solve this problem is to return an string, and format that string to json with JavaScriptSerializer.

    public string GetEntityInJson()
    {
       JavaScriptSerializer j = new JavaScriptSerializer();
       var entityList = dataContext.Entitites.Select(x => new { ID = x.ID, AnotherAttribute = x.AnotherAttribute });
       return j.Serialize(entityList );
    }

It is important the "Select" part, which choose the properties you want in your view.

This helps render a view with less data, just with the attributes you need, and makes your web run faster.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this kind of error can be risen when you try to serialize for example a class say class1 that reference by a property another class say class2 and in turn class2 reference with a property class1.  The circular reference is because from class1 you go to class2 and from class2 to class1

Answer (score 0):

Instruct the serializer to ignore the loop reference like:

```
var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myList, new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore});
```

And return it like:

```
return Json(new { data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Error: Request unknow parameter 'Id_category' for row 0 column 0.  :(

Comment: I check network XHR: is data?

"[{\"Id_category\":\"MILKTEA   \",\"Name_category\":\"Trà sữa             \",\"Parent\":\"CATE      \"},{\"Id_category\":\"MILKTEA   \",\"Name_category\":\"Trà sữa             \",\"Parent\":\"CATE      \"}]"